# Acoustical properties of a rectangular prism with one open end

Tags: physics, music-theory

I'm studying musical instrument design as a hobby, and could not find the answer to a question regarding instruments with a square-cross sectional bore. After seeing a design for a Paetzold square bass recorder, I've searched several recorder forums, Reddit AskPhysics and StackExchange with no luck while trying to find out what properties of a rectangular-prismatic bore differ from a cylindrical bore.

Let's say that I have a hollow rectangular prism and I attach an oscillator to one side. Would the location or functionality of the nodes be affected by an irregularly-shaped bore? How would the frequencies of the overtones in relation to the fundamental change?

Comment: might try https://music.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Hi, I know acoustics and musical signal processing, but I don't get your question. What is a hollow rectangular prims with an oscillator on one side ?   Do you have a simple motivating example of your problem ? You want to know the steady-wave solutions to the wave equation, right ? (the [modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode)). What is an irregularly-shaped bore ?

Comment: The Paetzold square bass recorder is an example of this. I was attempting to describe the inner tube of a cylindrical woodwind instrument, such as the clarinet or recorder, but instead of a circular cross section, it would have a square cross section. (This could be constructed out of four contiguous panels with a large length and small width that are attached in a fashion such as the Paetzold's) and yes, that is what I was looking for. An irregularly-shaped bore is any inner tube that is non-cylindrical. Apologies for poor wording - I haven't had much experience with acoustics.

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting here, but you might try asking this on the [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).